# Time synchronization errors with multiple computers

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am experiencing a string of time synchronization errors that I am struggling with.

I have two different computers, each of which is streaming data from a different sensor. I have set the time update on each computer to look at a common time server (sudo ntpdate {ip.address}).

- Computer A runs a Hokuyo, the roscore, a robot urdf, amcl, and a processing node (A_p) for the hokuyo data.
- Computer B runs a Kinect, two processing nodes accessing the kinect (B_p), a node (C_p) fusing data from the kinect and the processing node (A_p), and another node fusing information from all of the nodes (A_p, B_p, and C_p) on computer A and B, and transforming their locations into map space (generated by amcl).

This configuration generates synchronization errors, even though everything uses ros::Time::now() to retrieve time. When fusing data in node B_p, I get time synchronization errors:

---

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'tf::ExtrapolationException
what():  Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 1362173375.685855810 but the earliest data is at time 1362173375.907669363, when looking up transform from frame [/robot_tf/back_laser] to frame [/robot_tf/base_link]

---

and when transforming data into /map space, I get transformation errors that I am assuming are also time synchronization errors:

---

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'tf::LookupException'
what():  Frame id /robot_tf/base_link does not exist! Frames (6): Frame /robot_tf/camera2_depth_optical_frame exists with parent /robot_tf/camera2_depth_frame.

---

All of these processes work when on the same computer, but spread across 2 computers, they eventually fail... and eventually isn't very long. Can I get rid of these errors entirely? Barring that, how do I ignore these errors? Do I need to write my own exception handler, or is there something easy in ros already?

Thank you,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56778/time-synchronization-errors-with-multiple-computers/) by [ebeowulf](https://answers.ros.org/users/2856/ebeowulf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2013-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure if this is what's producing the error, but:

When dealing with message data and tf, I avoid using `ros:Time::now()` whenever possible. Instead, use the timestamp of each message.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2013-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest you go through the [tf Tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials) to know how to handle the exceptions correctly.  In any distributed setup it is expected that you will need to make your code robust to exceptions.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-03-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Also make sure that both machines are time synced to something. (e.g. using chrony, ntp, etc.) Otherwise you'll see laggy data in Rviz, and other fun stuff.

---

Originally posted by [Gav](https://answers.ros.org/users/3961/gav/) with karma: 478 on 2013-03-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2